# Trig function proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to confirm that $sin^2(x) = -2cos(x)$. I found it on this website: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/katelyn2.html

But I am having a little trouble seeing their proof. Specifically the step where they say $1-cos^2(x)=cos(x)$. Can someone perhaps explain?

Comment: That's an equation, not an identity. It only holds for specific values of $x$, not every $x$.

Comment: There is a mild error in the solution   provided, it should say $1-\cos^2 x=-2\cos x$.

Comment: therefore if If I have an equation that has $\frac{2-2cos(N\theta)}{2-2cos(\theta)}$, it becomes $\frac{2+sin^2(N\theta)}{2+sin^2(\theta)}$. Using the identity that $1-cos^2(x)=sin^2(x)$

Comment: The problem you linked to asks us to **solve** the equation $\sin^2 x=-2\cos x$, that is, to find the values of $x$ such that $\sin^2 x=-2\cos x$.  For almost all values of $x$, the equation does not hold. In particular, the calculation in the preceding comment is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin^2 x = -2\cos(x)$ is certainly not true, and you can check that by plugging in $x=0$ to get $\sin^2(0) = 0$ and $-2\cos(0) = -2\cdot 1 = -2$